# What does it mean when Google Analytics says that a bug causes doubled visit counts that are automatically corrected?

Tags: seo, google-analytics

When I logged into Google Analytic's account, I have set out this warning

Google Analytic's says: 
Universal properties created prior to December 2013 may temporarily report doubled Visits counts between the hours of 0500-0800 in the View timezone. This issue corrects itself automatically. We are working on a fix to address this issue as soon as possible.

What do you think about this issue??

Answer (score 1):

**I think** " *Universal properties created prior to December 2013 may temporarily report doubled Visits counts between the hours of 0500-0800 in the View timezone*" ***and that*** "This issue corrects itself automatically. We are working on a fix to address this issue as soon as possible."

Answer (score 1):

I'm very glad that they are correcting this bug.  We've noticed that for quite a while.  Our visit counts are often inflated in the morning and then fall later in the day.

It will be nice not to have to deal with the problem anymore once it is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Got that too. Yes it may show double the visitor count
Just ignore it. if your site is e-commerce site, then go for revenue not the visitor count.